# Ticks must be between 0 and and TimeOnly.MaxValue.Ticks

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-6.0, c#-10.0

I'm using .net core 6 which supports DateOnly and TimeOnly datatypes.Now, What I have sufferred from is I am selecting nullable TimeOnly column(TimeEnd) from table (table1) which gives exception as : Ticks must be between 0 and and TimeOnly.MaxValue.Ticks. (Parameter 'ticks')

```
var result = await (from s in _unitOfWork.Context.table1
               select new
            {
                Id = Convert.ToString(s.EventId),
                EndTimeC = s.TimeEnd,
                DateC = s.Date,
                StartTimeC = s.TimeBegin,
                Systemmodstamp = s.ModifiedDate}).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Try to check nullable before set the value, by using `?` operator

Comment: And what is the actual type of that column in database?

Comment: C# is a language of types. What is the type of `s.TimeEnd`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
public class Result
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public TimeOnly? EndTimeC {get;set;}
  public DateOnly? DateC {get;set;}
  public TimeOnly? StartTimeC {get;set;}
  public DateOnly? Systemmodstamp {get;set;}
}
```

then convert your response to new created object that allowing null values:

```
var result = await (from s in _unitOfWork.Context.table1
               select new Result
            {
                Id = Convert.ToString(s.EventId),
                EndTimeC = s.TimeEnd,
                DateC = s.Date,
                StartTimeC = s.TimeBegin,
                Systemmodstamp = s.ModifiedDate}).ToListAsync();
             };
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add code `EndTimeC = s.TimeEnd.HasValue ? s.TimeEnd.Value : default(TimeOnly)` to check if `TimeOnly` is `null` or not and based on it you can handle it.

alternative way is `EndTimeC = s.TimeEnd.GetValueOrDefault()`.